# phonegap - allow update of an apps database when the app isn't running

Tags: android, cordova

I'm writing a web app in phonegap and want to update the apps database with the latest data from my server, but do this as a background task without interaction from the user.

The Google Play store does this as it shows me updates automatically when I have a wifi connection without me having to open the Play store app.

Any ideas or help on how to achieve this is appreciated.

m

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)

It allows you to send messages to your phone from a server, also when the app is in background. If you dont want to implement the server application which fires the messages, you could run a background task as a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), but it needs to be initalized by starting the app at least 1 time after the phone has been booted. Also, it consumes battery power during running. I´d say the Google Cloud Messaging is a more classy solution.